# Add a (second) condition to delete empty rows from a table

Tags: vba, excel

with help of the code of PNRAO at AnalysisTabs, I found how to delete blank rows in a Table (ListObject; Code below). However, I have 1 column in the table that holds default 0,00 as value (it is a calculated numeric field) and I want remove empty rows even if the column for that row holds a value (i.e. 0,00).

So, my code now only remove rows when I clear the value in that column (@Totaal). How do I add the condition?

```
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DeclaratieSpecificatie").Range

For iCntr = rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1 To rng.Row Step -1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(iCntr)) = 0 Then Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

Comment: Could you change the `CountA` to `Sum`? That would identify both blank cells and cells with *0.00* as *0* for removal. Be cautious as it will also identify text based values as *0*.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Thanks! It actually does what I need it to do. Now, the only problem occurring is I get an error (Run time error 1004 - Delete method of Range class failed) and the debugger points to Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete. Any clue?

Comment: Problem resolved when setting .Range to .DataBodyRange in Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DeclaratieSpecificatie").DataBodyRange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved when setting .Range to .DataBodyRange in

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DeclaratieSpecificatie").DataBodyRange
```